# Laravel place query inside of controller or model class

Tags: php, laravel

```
#1
Class controller {
    $customer = Model\customer::find($id);
}

#2
Class controller {
    $customer = new Model\customer;
    $customer = $customer->data($id);
}

Class Model {
   public function data($id) {
        return self::find($id);
   }
}
```

I'm new in larava, I got a question about MVC query.

I saw many people put query inside of controller like #1

I usually like to put query inside of model class.

any suggestion?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me MVC means - Model View Controller.

In a general language **Model** should contain the Database Query related stuffs whereas in **View** you should always use variables to populate view data and at last **Controller** is generally for catching the requests and send the response by doing some logical functionality on request.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;

class ExampleModel
{
    // All the database related methods like - all, paginate, find, where, etc would goes in the model...
}
```

In case of Views

```
<html>
  ...
  YOUR_CONTENT_HERE
  ...
</html>
```

and in case of Controller,

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controllers;

class ExampleController
{
    public function index()
    {
       $request = request()->all();
       ... do some logical work here ...
       return response($data);
    }
}
```

Thats what MVC code structure would be like - in my opinion

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes i understand mvc, yet im new in laravel, and i have seen many ppl use model static method do query in controller, so u think i should go for #2?

Comment: Ya you can the MVC is not the hard and fast rule, but I think you should do DB Query related stuffs inside your model functions and call them from controller...

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to use the model's `find()` method directly to retrieve an entity.

If you are developing a larger application, you should, however, consider moving all the logic into your own classes. The controller should just collect the input from the http request, session etc. and call a method on a service to do the actual work. That way your code is not glued to a controller action or route.